# How to show query results in single page header.php in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, header, categories, product

I have a lot of pages in my project on PHP Codeigniter. I have one header.php page .. In header.php I need to get the categories in mysql query ... how can I do this for every page ?.
I need to do a mysql query for each header.php on each page .. I want to once  query for category.
thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to query DB every HTTP request, store first request query result in session variable or into local storage variable. MY_Controller pseudo code would be something like

```
if ( ! $this->session->userdata('header_categories') { 
    $header_categories =  $this->Category_m->get_all();
    $this->session->set_userdata('header_categories', $header_categories);
}
// otherwise data is already there and no need for DB query
```

In this session approach you could loop `$this->session->userdata('header_catogories')` in view file i.e. `header.php`
As you can see I mentioned MY_Controller class that should be present and every controller should extend that class. You need to set this part of code in constructor of MY_Controller.

Comment: thank you for your answer..But I guess I gave the missing information.I have a menu in my header.php.I have product categories in this menu...I need to pull this menu categories from the database.Would it be right to keep it in session userdata?

Comment: Can't tell more because I [didn't](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) see the code. Is that menu  public? Is it different per different users? Second way (beside sessions) I know is using local storage.